# Can't get user email from child index with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to get the user email in the Students index page but I keep returning 'undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  has_many :posts
  has_many :students
  belongs_to :role

end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :franchise
  belongs_to :preschool
end
```

In my students index page I have

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= student.user.email %></td>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `user` migration file? Because as it stands there is nothing in your code that says you have an `email` value (or method) in your `user` class.

Comment: @Nick can you please update question with exact error you got

Comment: @Haider I tried Rodrigo's solution below and it fixed the issue.  The problem was I needed to be using try, in the event a student isn't associated to a user.  In my case when testing some of my students didn't have users initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have `students` without `user`.

```
<td><%= student.user.try(:email) || 'Without User' %></td>
```